# onLocationCallback is not called on Lollipop Emulator with FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

With FusedLocationProviderClient,locationCallback does not get called on Lollipop Emulator. The emulator does not contain GOOGLE Play Services.The POP UP to enable location services pops up and the startLocationUpdates() method is called but the callback is not called. Is FusedLocationAPI supposed to worked without Goodle Play Services?

```
public class BasicHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;
private FrameLayout basicHomeFrameLayout;
private int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
private LinearLayout rootLayout;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private View actionView;
private ProgressBar locationLoader;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
private static String TAG = BasicHomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_home);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    basicHomeFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.basic_home_fragment);
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.basic_home_root_layout);


    //Adding Fragment to Home Activity
    replaceFragment(R.id.basic_home_fragment,new HomeFragment());
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    actionView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_layout, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionView);

    locationLoader = (ProgressBar) actionView.findViewById(R.id.location_loader);
    locationLoader.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

            Log.e("Location Callback","true");

            if (locationResult == null) {
                Log.e("Found Location","False");
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                Log.e("Found Location","True");
                findCompleteAddress(location);
                fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
            }
        };
    };

    checkFusedLocationSettings();
}

private void checkFusedLocationSettings() {

    LocationRequest locationRequest = createLocationRequest();
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            Log.e("Location Settings","true");
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("Location Failure",e.getMessage());
            if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                // by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(BasicHomeActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
            }
        }
    });
}



public void startLocationUpdates() {

    Log.e("Starting Location","true");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        Log.e("Permission Granted","false");
    }
    else {



        Log.e("Permission Granted","true");
        locationLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(createLocationRequest(),
                locationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);


    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    switch (requestCode) {
        case 200: {


            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    locationLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(createLocationRequest(),
                            locationCallback,
                            null /* Looper */);

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    return locationRequest;

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There must be a Google Play Service installed in emulator and also you need to set mock location in it.

Answer (score 0):

`FusedLocationProviderApi` is dependent on Google Play Services. Google Play Services must be installed on the device (or emulator).